# File "<stdin>", line 1 error y bash: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `('

Tags: python, linux, bash, stdin

Corro el código y me sale el primer error.

Después puse el comando `exit()` en la terminal pero me sale el problema delbash.

Ya instalé y desinstalé VSC y no se soluciona.

Ni el típico Hello World me compila y me manda errores parecidos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código que muestra no corresponde con el *trace*. Estas invocando el interprete de Python desde línea de comando e intentando ejecutar un `return randint(1,6)` sin más. El interprete te alega porque no has definido ninguna función. Luego intentas ejecutar el `return randint(1,6)` desde línea de comandos, y obvio, ese no es un comando de **bash**.

Comment: `error outside function` se produce en el código que publicó porque el `returm` no está identado con el `def` como advierte el interprete es error sintàctico

Comment: Estás pulsando Shift+Enter para tratar de ejecutar línea a línea el código. Eso no puedes hacerlo en el caso de la función, pues la línea que contiene el return por si sola no significa nada. Tienes que seleccionar el código de la función completa antes de pulsar Shift+Enter. En cualquier caso no recomiendo el método de ejecutar "por trozos" mediante Shift+Enter. Es mejor que escribas el código completo y lo pruebes completo en la terminal (por ejemplo con el botón "Play" de arriba a la derecha). Para esto asegúrate de que no tienes un intérprete interactivo abierto en la terminal.

Answer (score 1):

No sé qué estás tratando de hacer en tu terminal.

Primero activas tu ambiente virtual.

Luego, por algún motivo extraño, ejecutas el python del ambiente virtual (este ya se debería ejecutar con tan sólo poner `python`).

Luego, por otro motivo extraño sales de tu consola de python sin haber hecho nada y entras a bash.

Luego escribes `return randint(1,6)` en bash como si estuvieras dentro de python.

Me parece que quieres tan sólo ejecutar tu código dentro de dado. En ese caso tu código debería quedar algo así:

```py
from random import randint

def dado():
    return randint(1,6)

print(dado())
```

Y ese código lo llamas con: `python dado.py`, o cual sea su ruta.

Answer (score 1):

No estás ejecutando el script de la forma adecuada.

## Opción 1

Podrías hacer esto en en terminal:

```
/home/teo/Escritorio/blahblah/python dado.py
```

## Opción 2

O podrías colocar esto como primera línea de `dado.py`:

```
#!/home/teo/Escritorio/blahblah/python
```

Con eso, el script indica cual sería el intérprete que se debe utilizar para su ejecución.

Luego, seteas el bit de ejecución del script:

```
chmod +x dado.py
```

Y entonces podrías llamar directamente el script:

```
./dado.py
```

Y se debería ejecutar correctamente en python.

Como nota al margen, deberías quitar la imagen de la pregunta y pegar el texto. No importa que no sepas como editarlo para que quede formateado ya que algún editor va a entrar y le va a poner el formato adecuado.